# How to remove submit button from Request.Form collection after post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some MVC4 code that I am maintaining. A previous developer created a page with both a search button and a download button, and both are submit buttons.  After the page is posted, he checks `Request.Form("btnDownload") != null` to see if the download button has been clicked, which works fine BUT the download caused by that button does not return the view, it returns a `CSVResult` which returns a `.csv` file for Excel.  So then the next time the OTHER submit button is clicked, the `btnDownload` element is still not null, and the code thinks the download button has been clicked.

I tried another method for two submit buttons I found on Stack Overflow (adding a `Command` element with different values), but that method leaves all the buttons disabled when one is clicked.

I need a way to remove `btnDownload` from the post variables with JavaScript or any other way you can suggest to accomplish this.

I short, I have a search button and a download button both of which cause a post, but only the search button returns the view.  How can I put something in JavaScript at the beginning of the page that puts the `btnDownload` button in its initial state so that it will not be returned in `Request.Form`?

Here is the code.  This code is reused on a number of pages, this is just some search value text boxes, a search button, a Clear (reset search) button and a download button.

```html
@{    
    var filters = MetadataProviderHelper.GetModelMetadataForSearchFilterFields(@Model);

    var pageSize = (int)ViewBag.PageSize;
    var pageIndex = (int)ViewBag.PageIndex;
    var totalItemCount = (int)ViewBag.TotalItemCount;
    var sortColumn = string.Empty;
    var sortDir = string.Empty;     
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('#frmSearch .download').attr('value', null);
        $('.pagination a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = this.href;
            var len = url.length;
            var pos = url.indexOf('?page=') + 6;
            var page = url.substr(pos, len - pos);
            $('#frmSearch .pageNo').attr('value', page);          
            $('#frmSearch .download').attr('value', null);
            return $('#frmSearch').submit();

        });

        $('#frmSearch .pageSize').change(function () {
            $('#frmSearch .pageNo').attr('value', 1);
            $('#frmSearch .download').attr('value', null);
            return $('#frmSearch').submit();
        });


        $("#btnReset").click(function (e) {
            $("#frmSearch").find("input[type=text],select").each(function() {
                $(this).val("");
            });
        });
    });
</script>

@if (TempData["msg"] != null)
{
    <div><b>@(TempData["msg"].ToString())</b></div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(),
                        ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), 
                        FormMethod.Post,
                        new { @class = "form-inline", id="frmSearch", name="frmSearch"}))
{ 
<div class="well" id="SearchFilters">
    
    <fieldset>
        @foreach (ModelMetadata filter in filters)
        {      
            if (filter.PropertyName.Trim().ToLower() == "expertise")
            {
                <label for="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" style="vertical-align:middle;">@(filter.DisplayName):           
                    @Html.Raw("<br/>" + SiteHelper.GetUserProfileExpertiseListAsHtml(ViewData["Expertise"].ToString()) + "<br/><br/>")
                </label>
            }
            else if (filter.PropertyName.Trim().ToLower() == "subjectareas")
             {
                <label for="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" style="vertical-align:middle;">@(filter.DisplayName):           
                    @Html.Raw("<br/>" + SiteHelper.GetUserProfileSubjectAreaListAsHtml(ViewData["SubjectAreas"].ToString()) + "<br/>")
                </label>
             }
             else
             {
                <label for="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" style="width:250px;vertical-align:top;">@(filter.DisplayName):           
                 @switch (filter.TemplateHint.Trim().ToLower())
                  {
                      case "string":
                          @Html.TextBox(filter.PropertyName, filter.AdditionalValues[Globals.DefaultValueKey])
                          break;

                      case "dropdown":
                          var items = filter.AdditionalValues[Globals.DropdownAttributeValuesKey] as IEnumerable<Acceleron.Domain.SelectListItemDTO>;
                          var selectList = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", filter.AdditionalValues[Globals.DefaultValueKey] as string);

                          @Html.DropDownList(filter.PropertyName, selectList)
                          ;
                          break;

                      case "date":
                          @Html.TextBox(filter.PropertyName, filter.AdditionalValues[Globals.DefaultValueKey], new {@class = "date", title = filter.DisplayName})
                          break;
                    }
                    </label>
             }     
            
        }
        

        @if (filters != null && filters.Count > 0)
        {
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="float-right">
@*                <button type="submit" id="btnSearch" name='Command' class="btn  btn-inverse" value="Search">&nbsp;&nbsp;Search&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnReset" name="Command" class="btn" value="Clear">Clear</button>*@
                <button type="submit" id="btnSearch" name='btnSearch' class="btn  btn-inverse">&nbsp;&nbsp;Search&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnReset" name="btnReset" class="btn">Clear</button> 
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        }

        <span class="pull-right" style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;

            @if (totalItemCount > 0 &&
                ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() != "connect")
            {
            @*<button class="download" type="submit" id='btnDownload' name='Command' class="btn btn-primary ignore" value="Download">Download</button>*@
            <button type="submit" id='btnDownload' name='btnDownload' class="btn btn-primary ignore" value="">Download</button>
            }

            @if (ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() != "report" &&
                ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() != "connect")
            {            
            <a href="/admin/@ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()/edit" class="btn btn-warning">Add</a>
            }

            @if (ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "user" || ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "coupon")
            {
            <a href="/admin/@ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()/upload" class="btn btn-warning">Upload</a>
            }     
        </span>
        @Html.Hidden("PageIndex", @pageIndex, new { @class = "pageNo" })       
        @Html.Hidden("SortColumn", @sortColumn)
        @Html.Hidden("SortDirection", @sortDir)
    </fieldset>

</div>

            if (totalItemCount > 0)
            {
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul>
            @Html.Raw(@Html.Pager(@pageSize, @pageIndex, @totalItemCount))               
            </ul>
           
            <span class="pull-right">Page Size:&nbsp;
            <select id="PageSize" name="PageSize" style="width: 50px; margin-top: 3px;" class="pageSize">            
                <option value="25" @if (pageSize == 25)
                                   { @Html.Raw("Selected");
                                   }>25</option>
                <option value="50" @if (pageSize == 50)
                                   { @Html.Raw("Selected");
                                   }>50</option>
                    <option value="100" @if (pageSize == 100)
                                        { @Html.Raw("Selected");
                                        }>100</option>
                <option value="200" @if (pageSize == 200)
                                    { @Html.Raw("Selected");
                                    }>200</option>
                <option value="300" @if (pageSize == 300)
                                    { @Html.Raw("Selected");
                                    }>300</option>               
                <option value="500" @if (pageSize == 500)
                                    { @Html.Raw("Selected");
                                    }>500</option>
            </select>
            </span>
        </div>
            }
            else
            {
         @Html.Hidden("PageSize", "25", new { @class = "pageSize" })    
 }
 
    
}

<iframe id="download_target" name="download_target" src="" style="display:none; width: 0; height: 0;
        border: 0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

Comment: I provided the code requested.

Comment: Okay, I don't see any controller code, but try clearing the model state when `Request.Form("btnDownload") != null` by adding `ModelState.Clear();` before the end of the if statement.